# Создание сферы методом разбиения икосаэдра

Tags: c++, графика

В общем, надо сгенерировать сферу путем рекурсивного разбиения икосаэдра по 4 треугольника. Сделать надо без библиотек, на чистом win32 (не спрашивайте почему). Проблема в том, что я полный олух в компьютерной графике и все, на что меня хватило - рекурсивно разбить икосаэдр (на самом деле рекурсии тут нет, я посчитал что без нее будет меньше лишнего рисования, да и не получилось у меня нормально с рекурсией сделать, буду рад если кто-нибудь предложит вариант с рекурсией, интересно посмотреть что было не так у меня).

```
CTriangle c[5000];
int size = 0;
int prevsize = 0;

void DivideTriangle(CTriangle ct, HDC hdc) {
    CVertex b1, b2, b3;
    b1.x = (ct.a2.x + ct.a3.x) / 2;
    b1.y = (ct.a2.y + ct.a3.y) / 2;
    b2.x = (ct.a1.x + ct.a3.x) / 2;
    b2.y = (ct.a1.y + ct.a3.y) / 2;
    b3.x = (ct.a1.x + ct.a2.x) / 2;
    b3.y = (ct.a1.y + ct.a2.y) / 2;
    CTriangle dt = CTriangle(hdc, b1, b2, b3);
    CTriangle dt1 = CTriangle(hdc, ct.a1, b2, b3);
    CTriangle dt2 = CTriangle(hdc, b1, ct.a2, b3);
    CTriangle dt3 = CTriangle(hdc, b1, b2, ct.a3);
    c[size] = dt;
    c[size + 1] = dt1;
    c[size + 2] = dt2;
    c[size + 3] = dt3;
    size += 4;
    if (_recurslevel == 0) {
        dt.DrawTriangle();
        dt1.DrawTriangle();
        dt2.DrawTriangle();
        dt3.DrawTriangle();
    }
};
void DrawLoop(HDC hdc) {
    while (prevsize < size) {
        DivideTriangle(c[prevsize],hdc);
        prevsize++;
        if (prevsize >= normalRecursion) break;
    }
    for (int i = prevsize; i < size; i++) {
        c[i].DrawTriangle();
    }
}
```

normalRecursion - этот тот же _recurslevel, преобразованный для работы с массивом, а _recurslevel - непосредственно глубина рекурсии. 
CVertex и CTriangle - вершина и треугольник, там ничего не обычного.
[image: Икосаэдр]

Собственно вопрос - что надо сделать, чтоб этот икосаэдр превратить в сферу? Ну, то есть, понятно что надо на каждом этапе, скажем так, рекурсии, не отрисовывать некоторые элементы и что-то с чем-то соединять, но я не понимаю как и что и по какому алгоритму, а голову ломать уже не хватает времени. Буду рад любым мыслям, предложениям, книжкам, коду, статьям, ибо сам не нашел. Заранее благодарю

PS. Сделал рекурсивно, но по-прежнему не понимаю как положить вершины на сферу

```
void DivideTriangle(CTriangle ct,  int depth) {
        if (depth == 0)
        {
            ct.DrawTriangle();
            return;
        }
        CVertex b1, b2, b3;
        b1.x = (ct.a2.x + ct.a3.x) / 2;
        b1.y = (ct.a2.y + ct.a3.y) / 2;
        b2.x = (ct.a1.x + ct.a3.x) / 2;
        b2.y = (ct.a1.y + ct.a3.y) / 2;
        b3.x = (ct.a1.x + ct.a2.x) / 2;
        b3.y = (ct.a1.y + ct.a2.y) / 2;

        CTriangle dt = CTriangle(hdc, b1, b2, b3);
        CTriangle dt1 = CTriangle(hdc, ct.a1, b2, b3);
        CTriangle dt2 = CTriangle(hdc, b1, ct.a2, b3);
        CTriangle dt3 = CTriangle(hdc, b1, b2, ct.a3);
        DivideTriangle(dt,  depth - 1);
        DivideTriangle(dt1,  depth - 1);
        DivideTriangle(dt2,  depth - 1);
        DivideTriangle(dt3,  depth - 1);
    };
```

Comment: "а голову ломать уже не хватает времени" - как я сейчас проникнусь этой причиной!

Comment: Вообще-то, как я понимаю, каждый треугольник надо было превращать в тетраэдр, вершина которого тоже лежит на сфере. И это действительно проще делать рекурсивно.

Answer (score 0):

b1.x = (ct.a2.x + ct.a3.x) / 2;
    b1.y = (ct.a2.y + ct.a3.y) / 2;

А где z?
Почему разбивается проекция а не сам икосаэдр.
Надо то же самое сделать с z
Потом поделить вектор вершины на его длину
Потом умножить его на радиус шара

Comment: ИМХО, есть смысл добавить вводную часть в Ваш ответ.

Comment: Не задавайте вопросов в ответе, используйте утвердительные формулировки.